# Intercepting PHP mail() with a Java class

Tags: java, email, php

I have a LAMP setup. I'm trying to intercept the mail() command and call my own Java code instead of calling sendmail etc. I've altered the php.ini

```
sendmail_path = /home/jlarkins/Desktop/CustomMail
```

which is my Java class file. Problem is, whenever I try to test this via a PHP test emailer, nothing happens. Can someone help me out, point me to the proper log file for Java errors or correct the syntax I'm using? I don't care that it won't send the email, I don't want the email going out anyways. I just want to trap it and analyze via my own Java code.

Comment: Is your java class file executable? If not, you may need to bootstrap it with a shell script.

Comment: It has a main method if that's what you mean? Or do you mean it needs to be a JAR?

Comment: Java classes or JARs are usually run using the "java" command, e.g. "java CustomMail" or "java -jar CustomMail.jar". You can't just invoke them from the command line or from a script, which is probably what php is trying to do. What OS is this on?

Comment: Huzzah, Linux! In that case, what r3c suggests below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your PHP/Apache error log file to see if anything can be found there.

Is "CustomMail" a .class file? If yes, it is not an executable file, thus PHP cannot run it. You'll have to point your sendmail_path variable on an executable file which will load your Java program and forward its arguments.

Something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -r CustomMail.class ] && java CustomMail $@
```

Comment: I'm trying this, but of course I'm new to the linux world. I copied the two lines of code above into a file, named it MailWrapper.bin, and tried to run it by itself from the command line. Only response is    MailWrapper.bin : command not found

Comment: You'll have to make it executable, e.g. "chmod +x MailWrapper.bin" and then invoke like this "./MailWrapper.bin" or by specifying the full path to the script, e.g. "/home/jlarkins/Desktop/MailWrapper.bin"